# Dynamic programming:Making a Change

Tags: algorithms, recursive-algorithms, dynamic-programming

I'm practicing  problems on dynamic programming.The problem is as follows:

You are given n types of coin denominations of values v(1) < v(2) < ... < v(n)  (all integers). Assume v(1) = 1, so you can always make change for any amount of
money C. Give an algorithm which makes change for an amount of money C with as
few coins as possible.

Here is the solution which i have figured out..

So,the idea is to make a change such that we need fewer coins in making that be it of any denomination.

So,this is all about choices...
   If i need for 1 dollar i have one option i.e to select v1 -----> (1) this is an option

If for example ,we are making a change for 10 dollars

```
     --->pick ten 'one' dollar notes
     ---->pick two  'five dollar notes
     ----->pick a  'ten' dollar note itself..
```

we need to calculate the minimum of these choices and return it as our
   solution.

Is the approach i'm following is correct?

Comment: I can't catch your idea. Can you explain more? Maybe there will be a more instructive example. You did not mention which types of coin denomination you have. why don't you check five one-dollar and oen five-dollar notes?

Comment: @miracle173 i have a one dollar,five dollar for suppose and i'm planning to make a change for 10 dollars.So i've explored all my possibilites like 1*(10) or 2*(5) or 1*5+5*1 and select the minimum choice and output it as my answer..my question is..is the approach correct?

Comment: so which coin values do you have and how many of them? Why don't you check five one-dollar and one five-dollar coins?

Comment: @miracle173 I've mentioned it in the reply ...that i have  one dollar,five dollar and the question doesnot ask for "how many of them".Since,it is not mentioned in the question about that..considering your suggestion i have added 1*5+5*1 in the reply..all i'm asking is to tell me whether the approach i followed is correct? or not? for dynamic programming?

Comment: no, this is not a dynamic programming approach.

Comment: @miracle173 why is this not? i'm making all choices and picking the miinimum out of it right?

Answer (score 1):

Trying all possible solutions is an *exhaustive search*. The following is a dynamic programming algorithm.
The minimal solution we search for can be defined recursively:

```
if m=v(k), for a k, then:
    coins_needed(m):=1, 
otherwise:   
    coins_needed(m):=
        min(coins_needed(1)+coins_needed(m-1),
        coins_needed(2)+coins_needed(m-2),
        ...,
        coins_needed(floor(m/2)+coins_needed(ceiling(m/2)))
```

One can start with m=1 and , then calculate coins_needed for m=2 and so on. It is important to store all the minimal solution one has calculated so far, otherwise the algorithm needs an  exponential running time.

If one has calculated coins_needed(m-1) in this way, one has already calculated coins_needed(1),...,coins_needed(m-2) and stored the results. It is now easy to calculate coins(m) according to the above formula.

It is [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) as defined in Wikipedia, The problem has [optimal substructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_substructure), because the problem solution can be constructed of the solution of the smaller subproblems, and each subproblem can be broken in smaller sub problems again but we have [overlapping subproblems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlapping_subproblems). This means we have always the same sub problems that can be reused. So if we store the results of the subproblems (memoization) we can reuse them.

Answer (score 1):

To help you get the idea: suppose you want to make $\$20$. Instead of trying all the possible combinations (brute force), suppose that you already know the optimum way of making   $\$19$ (let call $n(19)$ the number of coins needed for that, and $d(19)$ the list of coins needed).

Sure, we could add one $\$1$ coin, and conclude that $n(20)=n(19)+1$, but this would be wrong, this is not necessarily optimal - perhaps combining the sum of $\$15$ plus a $\$5$ coin does better. (important: $n(j)$ is not necessarily increasing).

However, if we not only know $n(19)$ (the optimum for the previous step), but also $n(j)$ for all $1\le j < 20$, then we can compute all the alternatives $n(j)+n(20-j)$ and pick the minimum (unless there is a coin with $v_k=20$). So one algorithm is:

$$ n(j)=\cases{1 & if $ v_k=j$ for some $k$\\
\min_{i=1 \cdots j-1}n(i)+n(j-i) & elsewhere}
$$

This starts with $n(1)=1$. 
A similar recursion, with concatenations instead of sums, allows to build $d(j)$, the optimum lists of coins.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leonbloy/uvq6pcq0/)